# Oracle Join Tables With Nulls

Tags: sql, oracle, join, null

I have two tables with a unique key. Below are examples of keys in the table

```
Table A                      Table B
1                              3
2                              4
3
4
Null
Null
Null
```

I want to join Table A to Table B where the keys match or Table A has a null value.

```
The desired result set would be
3
4
Null
Null
Null
```

I've tried a.key is null or a.key = b.key, but that is getting many many rows returned that I believe are duplicates. Also, here's the weird thing if do a.key is null or a.key = (select b.key from b where b.key = a.key) it works, but I want to avoid a subselect.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: why 2 NULLs why not 3 NULLs ???

Comment: Looking at your input and desired output, it is impossible to do it in **SQL**, impossible to do it **logically**. Please explain the **RULE(s)** how you want to manipulate `NULL`.

Comment: Should be three Nulls in the desired results.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
SELECT somecolumn
FROM   a
JOIN   b
ON a.somecolumn = b.anothercolumn
UNION ALL
SELECT somecolumn FROM a
WHERE somecolumn is null;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ea6af/2